# How can I make the errors shown in the console refer to the typescript source maps in an angular cli project?

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, angular-cli, source-maps

I have just issued the `ng new exampleProject` command. When an error appears in the console, the stacktrace shows only `.js` files: not the `.ts` files. How can I change this?

Here is an example of such an error:

[image: angular error]

Comment: You are getting errors running `ng new`? A little more information on what exactly you are seeing would be good.

Comment: @R.Richards No. I am refering to any errors that occur in the application. See the modified question

Comment: I see. You should see the `ts` file in the console if the error was from something in a `ts` file. Unless you have turned off source maps for some reason. I just added a `throw` to my app component, and the first thing I see in the stack trace is a link to the `ts` file, and the line number in it. Like so: `at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:17)'

Answer (score 3):

`console.trace()`

The above code helps to get the complete trace of where the error has occurred in angular including the line number, component name and the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"sourceMap": true,` in `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`